# SQL query - first value matching sum result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to get a specific value via an sql query based on a sum condition.

The idea is that I need a specific minimum_qty of a product to reduce its delivery time. In the example that value would be "2". The idea is that the query sums up the pop_supplied_qty column until its >= minimum_qty.

The queries result should be the pop_order_num where that condition is first met (653).

The current query looks like this:

```
CASE
    WHEN (sum(pop.pop_qty) - sum(pop.pop_supplied_qty)) >= minimum_qty
        THEN MIN(pop.pop_order_num)
    END AS pre_order_dt
```

Table:
[image]

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with inline variables and some sub-queries to:

- order the records by product and then pre-order number;
- add values for cumulative sum, resetting it when a record has a different product reference, and setting a boolean to true when the sum crosses the minimum threshold;
- filter for the records where the cumulative quantity was marked as having crossed the minimum threshold.

I have assumed that the `minimum_qty` is stored in a `product` table:

```
select product_id,
       minimum_qty,
       pop_order_num,
       cumul_qty
from  (
      select @newqty := if(@p = product_id, @qty, 0) + qty,
             (@qty < minimum_qty and @newqty >= minimum_qty) filter,
             @p := product_id as product_id,
             minimum_qty,
             pop_order_num,
             @qty := @newqty as cumul_qty
      from  (
            select   pop.product_id,
                     pop.pop_order_num,
                     pop.pop_qty - pop.pop_supplied_qty as qty,
                     p.minimum_qty
            from     pre_order_dt pop
            inner join product p on p.product_id = pop.product_id 
            order by product_id,
                     pop_order_num
            limit    10000000000
            ) as base,
            (select @qty := 0) as init
      ) as extend
 where filter
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3be5d/4).

Note that the `limit` clause is just a precaution, because the MySql engine does not have to obey the `order by`, since it occurs in an inner query. By adding the `limit` clause (which should specify a very high value so it does not actually leave out any record), MySql will be forced to apply the `order by` before processing the queries this inner query is wrapped in.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Could you let me know whether this was of use to you?